# Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync The code worked correctly. Why an internal error has occurred?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Previously the code worked correctly. Why an internal error has occurred?

Is this a problem with the JavaScript API for Office?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form

The link and title are correct. I checked it out.

```
                  var options = {
                    asyncContext: null
                  };


                  Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(link, title, options, function (asyncResult) {
                    console.log("asyncResult: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
                    if (asyncResult.status === "succeeded") {
                      $docName.prepend("<i class='ms-Icon ms-Icon--checkbox ms-font-m ms-fontColor-green'>");
                      $fileProcess.resolve();
                    } else {
                      console.log("Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync() [" + asyncResult.status + "] error: "//
                        + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error) + " value: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value));
                      $fileProcess.reject();
                      $attachedDoc.addClass("ms-bgColor-error");
                      $docName.prepend("<i class='ms-Icon ms-Icon--alert ms-font-m ms-fontColor-error'></i>");
                      $docName.after("<div class='ms-ListItem-tertiaryText addedError'>" + asyncResult.error.message + "</div>");
                    }
                  });
```

I got an asyncResult:

```
asyncResult: {"value":null,"status":"failed","error":{"name":"Internal Error","message":"An internal error has occurred."}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a self-signed certificate.